# DELPHI INDY - Can not find parameter to activate UTF8 encoding/decoding

Tags: delphi, utf-8, indy

I'm using Delphi 10.3 and have created a `TIdTCPServer` and a client.
I found that Unicode characters like `ÅÄÖ` are changed when sent.

```pascal
ContexClient.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
ContexClient.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('abcÅÄÖ');
```

In the code above, I tried to fix that with the `DefStringEncoding` property, but the compiler doesn't find `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8`.

I've no idea what to do to get it working.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indy’s default encoding is US-ASCII.  That can be changed at runtime using the `GIdDefaultTextEncoding` variable in Indy’s `IdGlobal` unit.  You can set it to `encUTF8`, for instance.

That is why you see non-ASCII characters being changed. Using the `TIdIOHandler.DefStringEncoding` property is one solution for that.  `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8` is declared in the `IdGlobal` unit.  Make sure that unit is added to your `uses` clause.

`TIdIOHandler.WriteLn()` itself also has an optional `AByteEncoding` input parameter.  If it is `nil`, `DefStringEncoding` is used.  If that is also `nil`, `GIdDefaultTextEncoding` is used.

Comment: Thank's, I had already added that unit but DELPHI red-marked it so I decided, without try compile, that this unit wasn't available. After your answer I decided to compile and then the red mark dissappeared. I'm not sure why DELPHI, time to time errormark identifiers when they are ok. It's a bit irritating I would say. Hovever now everything is alright. :-)